# How can I get the parent thats positioned relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Suppose I have something like

```
<body>
    <article style="left: xxx; top: xxx">...</article>
    <article style="left: xxx; top: xxx">...</article>
    <article style="left: xxx; top: xxx">...</article>
</body>
```

My objective is to find in what "sector" is the element in, eg. Top/Bottom Left/Right. Then add classes for styling. So I suppose I will

1. find the parent thats positioned relative
2. get its width & height and from there calculate where the article/element is

I know that my articles are positioned relative to the body, but how can I get that dynamically with JS/jQuery. I am creating a plugin so I don't want to hardcode whats the parent thats positioned relative.

Comment: Couldn't you just give each article an id or class, "Top/Bottom/Left/Right", and get the id of the parent instead of doing some complicated calculation?

Comment: How do you want to judge which "sector" the element is in?

Comment: @Peter Of The Corn, for now I use that, I was thinking maybe to cutr down some markup and to challenge myself abit, I try that

Comment: @J-P, my width/height of parent compared to the left/top of element

Comment: Challenging your self is fine, but be aware that the use of javascript (JS) is to enhance the user experience. In this question, if you used JS it wouldnt degrade gracefully and therefore shouldnt be used. Use basic CSS and XHTML if you can. #justsaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex Thomas is absolutely correct about proper use of javascript to enhance user experience in a way which loads quickly and degrades gracefully.

Anyway, here's a quick proof of concept jsfiddle that does what you described:

**[Quadrant Based Classes](http://jsfiddle.net/skPY3/2/)**

Source (Rough) :

```
var $articles = $("article");
$articles.each(function(){
   var $which = $(this);
   var $parent = $which.parent(); 
   var className = "";

   var pHeight =$parent.outerHeight();
   //alert($which.offset().top + " <> " + (pHeight/2));
   if($which.offset().top < (pHeight/2)){
       className += "Bottom";
   } else {
       className += "Top";
   }

   var pWidth =$parent.outerWidth();
   //alert($which.offset().left + " <> " + (pWidth /2));        
    if($which.offset().left < (pWidth/2)){
        className +="Left";
    } else {
        className +="Right";
    }
    $which.addClass(className);
});
```